Напишите, пожалуйста, порядок действий решения задачи
Есть такого рода код:
   #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct Car {
    string name;
    string model;
    string year;
    Car(string n, string v,string b):name(n),model(v),year(b){}
};


struct Node {
    Car car;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    int count = 1;
    Node(Car c) : car(c), left(nullptr),right(nullptr){}

};



Node* findMin(Node* root) {
    while (root->left != nullptr) {
        root = root->left;
    }
    return root;
}


Node* insert(Node* root, Car car) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return new Node(car);
    }

    if (car.name < root->car.name ||
        (car.name == root->car.name && car.model < root->car.model) ||
        (car.name == root->car.name && car.model == root->car.model && car.year < root->car.year)) {
        root->left = insert(root->left, car);
    }
    else if (car.name > root->car.name ||
        (car.name == root->car.name && car.model > root->car.model) ||
        (car.name == root->car.name && car.model == root->car.model && car.year > root->car.year)) {
        root->right = insert(root->right, car);
    }
    else {
        root->count++;
    }
    return root;
}

Node* deleteNode(Node* root, Car car) {
    if (root == nullptr) return root;

    if (car.name < root->car.name ||
        (car.name == root->car.name && car.model < root->car.model) ||
        (car.name == root->car.name && car.model == root->car.model && car.year < root->car.year)) {
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, car);
    }
    else if (car.name > root->car.name ||
        (car.name == root->car.name && car.model > root->car.model) ||
        (car.name == root->car.name && car.model == root->car.model && car.year > root->car.year)) {
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, car);
    }
    else {
        if (root->count > 1) {
            root->count--;
        }
        else {
            if (root->left == nullptr) {
                Node* temp = root->right;
                delete root;
                return temp;
            }
            else if (root->right == nullptr) {
                Node* temp = root->left;
                delete root;
                return temp;
            }
            else {
                Node* temp = findMin(root->right);
                root->car = temp->car;
                root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->car);
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}

void print(Node* root) {
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        print(root->left);
        cout << "Марка: " << root->car.name << "\t";
        cout << "Модель: " << root->car.model << "\t";
        cout << "Год выпуска: " << root->car.year << "\t";
        cout << "В наличии " << root->count << endl;
        print(root->right);
    }

}











void main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);  
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
    
    
    Node* root = nullptr;
    root = insert(root,Car("Тойта","Королла","2012"));
    root = insert(root, Car("Тойта", "Королла", "2011"));
    root = insert(root, Car("Тойта", "Королла", "2013"));
    root = insert(root, Car("Тойта", "Королла", "2012"));
    
    int vb=10;
    while (vb!=0)
    {


        cout << "Выберите вариант действия:" << endl;
        cout << "1 - Просмотр всех машин." << endl;
        cout << "2 - Купить машину." << endl;
        cout << "3 - Вернуть/сдать в Trade In машину." << endl;
        cout << "0 - Выйти из автосалона." << endl;
        cin >> vb;
        switch (vb)
        {
            case 1: {
                print(root);
                break;
            }
            case 0: {
                return;
            }
            case 3: {
                string name1;
                string model1;
                string year1;
                cout << "Марка: "; cin >> name1; cout << endl;
                cout << "Модель: "; cin >> model1; cout << endl;
                cout << "Год выпуска: "; cin >> year1; cout << endl;

                root = insert(root, Car(name1,model1,year1));
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                string delName;
                string delModel;
                string delYear;
                cout << "Марка: "; cin >> delName; cout << endl;
                cout << "Модель: "; cin >> delModel; cout << endl;
                cout << "Год выпуска: "; cin >> delYear; cout << endl;
                root=deleteNode(root, Car(delName,delModel,delYear));
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}

как переписать добавление и удаление, программа не удаляет и не добавляет именно машины написанные кириллицей


Дерево должно быть упорядочено. Чтобы был быстрый поиск по нему. 2. А это спрашивайте у своего преподавателя. Вероятно, вы сейчас проходите тему "Деревья". 3. Тут без мата сложно обойтись... Генераторы ему... Это явно учебное задание, достаточно ввести данные нескольких автомобилей. Да, вручную! 4. Инфа об одном авто хранится в модели, которой является класс/структура. Инфа о многих авто хранится в дереве.


Если бы меня там чему то учили, а не только задания давали, обязательно бы спросил:) про от руки действительно без мата сложно, тк у меня нет ясности, на этот счет, тк прошлый препод говорил в духе «все вносить в ручную плохо, если я попрошу тебя от руки 1000 чисел написать, напишешь», и так с любой задачей, по этому я и задаю такие, казалось бы ненужные вопросы, ведь мне не поясняют ее решение в вузе, а в силу того, что я не имею достаточно опыта и не имею 7 пядей во лбу, решил уточнить у состоявшихся программистов, а не сдавать лютую хрень просто что смог и первое в голову пришло

Попробуй:

Определить структуру данных - вся общая информация об авто: модель, характеристики и т.п.;
Судя по всему по задаче нужно использовать двоичное дерево, тогда придется определять его структуру, содержать оно будет инфу об авто и собственно ссылки на левое и правое поддерево. Сюда бы и функции реализовать дефолтные - вставка узла, поиск узла и т.п.;
ИНициализируй - какой-нибудь массив, думаю можно и статический, который просто сформирует данные обо всех авто, а из него вводи данные в двоичное дерево;

Насчет вопросов:

Не очень понял сути вопроса, но если выводится информация об одном авто, то и упорядочивать данные не надо, элемент все-таки один;
Дерево тут скорее нужно для быстрого поиска, чтобы избежать линейного поиска, если бы это был односвязный список или массив;
Насчет генераторов не знаю:)
Хранить можно что в текстовике по типу
Модель,Тип кузова,Количество дверей, ..., а можно постараться и сделать все красиво в json файлике

[
    {
        "модель": "Toyota Camry",
        "тип_кузова": "Седан",
        "количество_дверей": 4,
        ....


Напиши, пожалуйста, пример как инициализировать, что в массив поместить и как его подвязать к дереву, я не умею, не представляю как писать( на сколько я понял нужен массив массивов, но как туда поместить данные с файла того же csv, или лучше exel, и тем более это связать к дереву, если дерево это корень цифра, слева цифры меньше корня, справа больше, каждый узел должен быть индексом массива просто?
